# wordpress: different pages have different menu layout and places

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress and I have follwoing issue:

I have used one theme and noticed that when I click on different pages from the menu that they show different places and layout of menu.

Example:
when I click the first page "Willkommen" from the menu, I get this menu layout (wrong layout):
[image]

When I click the second page "Über uns" from the same menue, I get this menu layout (correct layout):
[image]

you can try it out yourself here: dev2.haado.net/

Question: what can I check? I removed Willkommen page and recreated it again but same behaviour.

menu configuration:
[image]

UPDATE:
all pages that I create display the menu location/layout in the following screenshot. When I use exisiting page from the theme it uses the location/layout you can see in the second screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Themes that have multiple locations for the menu have an option to select locations your menu should appear in.

Selecting multiple locations for the same menu is also allowed.

For example, if the theme you picked has 4 menu locations, you either can have 4 different menus to display in those or have the same menu showing in 4 locations.

To select the locations just go back to Appearance -> Menus select any menu and at the bottom, you would see tick boxes of available locations.

Very likely what happens is that your selected theme allows you to specify different menus for different post types, so you can control user flow more precisely.

Comment: I have checked the pages "Willkommen" and "Über uns" have the same Menu and have only one location "Primary menu" please check new screen shoot in the main post

Comment: If you want the same menu on all pages - tickbox all locations.

Comment: It seems that the new created pages do not take layout of the menu somehow.

Comment: where to find this option?